# Generating desirable JSON format in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json

I amnot familiar php arrays. Therefore I couldn't solve that problem :

My data comes from database. I didn't post database connection parts, they work perfectly. As I understand I need to use multidimensional array. My Json format should be like this

```
{
   "monthly":[
      {
         "id":1,
         "name":"This is a JSON event",
         "startdate":"2016-9-15",
         "enddate":"2016-9-15",
         "starttime":"12:00",
         "endtime":"2:00",
         "color":"#FFB128",
         "url":""
      },
      {
         "id":2,
         "name":"This is a JSON event",
         "startdate":"2019-3-25",
         "enddate":"2019-3-25",
         "starttime":"12:00",
         "endtime":"23:00",
         "color":"#EF44EF",
         "url":""
      }
   ]
}
```

My PHP script (relevant part) :

```
try {
    $q = "SELECT * FROM eventcalendar";
    $res = $db->prepare($q);
    $res->execute();

    if ($res->rowCount() != 0) {
        $data = array('monthly' => array());
        $push_array = array();

        foreach ($res as $key) {
            $data['monthly']['id'] = $key['id'];
            $data['monthly']['name'] = $key['name'];
            $data['monthly']['startdate'] = $key['startdate'];
            $data['monthly']['enddate'] = $key['startdate'];
            $data['monthly']['color'] = $key['color'];
            $data['monthly']['starttime'] = 12;
            $data['monthly']['endtime'] = 12;
            $data['monthly']['url'] = "";

            array_push($push_array, $data);
        }

        file_put_contents('../js/events.json', json_encode($push_array));
        echo('<div class="alert alert-success resultsuccess" ><h4 class="alert-heading">Successful!</h4></div>');
    }
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo('<div class="alert alert-danger resultsuccess" >'.'Error: '.$e->getMessage().'</div>');
}
```

I get that JSON format

```
[
   {
      "monthly":{
         "id":"1",
         "name":"test1",
         "startdate":"2019-03-29",
         "enddate":"2019-03-29",
         "color":"#ffb128",
         "starttime":12,
         "endtime":12,
         "url":""
      }
   },
   {
      "monthly":{
         "id":"2",
         "name":"test2",
         "startdate":"2019-03-29",
         "enddate":"2019-03-29",
         "color":"#4263e6",
         "starttime":12,
         "endtime":12,
         "url":""
      }
   }
]
```

Thanks for reading...

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that you are creating new arrays with a `monthly` index on each pass through your loop, instead of pushing the new data into the existing `monthly` array. Try this instead:

```
    if ($res->rowCount() != 0) {
        $push_array = array('monthly' => array());
        $data = array();
        foreach ($res as $key) {
            $data['id'] = $key['id'];
            $data['name'] = $key['name'];
            $data['startdate'] = $key['startdate'];
            $data['enddate'] = $key['startdate'];
            $data['color'] = $key['color'];
            $data['starttime'] = 12;
            $data['endtime'] = 12;
            $data['url'] = '';
            array_push($push_array['monthly'], $data);
        }
```